# Send email with wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a cafe shop where people can order some items without registration. They should fill a form about their name, phone, email after that order something. The owner of a cafe needs to receive mail about orders after that deliver users order. My question is - is it possible to do that without registration and do I need woocoomerce for sending email to owner or I can do that without woocommerce, if it is possible then how?

I searched and find ways only with woocommerce.

Comment: This is not a forum where you can ask opinions or questions. For this kind of questions please use reddit.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only send email after the complete form, you can use plugin contact form 7. 
This is url to plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) once the form has been submitted

Answer (score 0):

Any form plugin in WordPress should be able to handle that task. You can, for example, use Caldera Form and then use Caldera's built-in processors.

Caldera Forms comes with 4 processors. One of those being Auto Responder – Sends an email on form submission. The Auto Responder processor would be a good fit for handling your task.

[Read more about Caldera form processors](https://calderaforms.com/doc/using-form-processors/)